# Build a basic cube with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, olap, olap-cube

I was wondering if `numpy` could be used to build the most basic cube model where all cross-combinations and their computed value are stored.

Let's take the following example of data:

```
AUTHOR         BOOK          YEAR        SALES
Shakespeare    Hamlet        2000        104.2
Shakespeare    Hamlet        2001        99.0
Shakespeare    Romeo         2000        27.0
Shakespeare    Romeo         2001        19.0
Dante          Inferno       2000        11.6
Dante          Inferno       2001        12.6
```

And to be able to build something like:

```
                             YEAR                  TOTAL
AUTHOR            BOOK       2000       2001         
(ALL)             (ALL)      142.8      130.6      273.4
Shakespeare       (ALL)      131.2      118.0      249.2
Dante             (ALL)      11.6       12.6       24.2
Shakespeare       Hamlet     104.2      99.0       203.2
Shakespeare       Romeo      27.0       19.0       46.0
Dante             Inferno    11.6       12.6       24.2
```

I'm hoping that the usage of using something like [`meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) might get me 75% there. Basically, I'd like to see if it's possible to build a structure of all pre-computed values with `numpy` (not pandas) to build a structure so that I could retrieve the above result of all possible combination. For the sake of simplicity, let's only consider the `SUM` as the only possible calculation. Perhaps this is a roundable way of asking, but could `numpy` be the backbone of doing this, or do I need to use something else?

And finally, if not possible in `numpy` how might this be stored in a MDA?

Comment: What is "a cube model"? Is there some reference material you could link here?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it's hard to summarize in a few sentences, but basically it's like a pivot table in excel, where the 'dimensions' (such as the author, book, and year) are used to group the data, and then the 'measures' are used to calculate something for each combination of dimensions. But in short, it's a "pivot table". Here's the wikipedia which has a pretty decent summary: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP_cube.

Comment: numpy is designed to work with unstructured numerical types. I would have thought that automatically disqualifies it from something like this

Comment: This looks more like a job for [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html), which is build on top of NumPy. Are you committed to NumPy or would that be an option?

Comment: @Timus I bet pandas could do this easily but I'd like to see a level lower than that where there aren't so many abstractions (pandas.pivot is a good start and I use that quite a bit).

Comment: I think you may want to explore [`xarray`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/)

Comment: @norok2 cool! Want to show an example in an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think `numpy` **record arrays** can be used for this task, below is my solution based on record arrays.

```
class rec_array():
    
    def __init__(self,author=None,book=None,year=None,sales=None):
        self.dtype = [('author','<U20'), ('book','<U20'),('year','<U20'),('sales',float)]
        self.rec_array = np.rec.fromarrays((author,book,year,sales),dtype=self.dtype)
        
    def add_record(self,author,book,year,sales):
        new_rec = np.rec.fromarrays((author,book,year,sales),dtype=self.dtype)
        if not self.rec_array.shape == ():
            self.rec_array = np.hstack((self.rec_array,new_rec))
        else:
            self.rec_array = new_rec
    
    def get_view(self,conditions):
        """
        conditions: 
            A list of conditions, for example 
            [["author",<,"Shakespeare"],["year","<=","2000"]]
        """
        mask = np.ones(self.rec_array.shape[0]).astype(bool)
        for item in conditions:
            field,op,target = item
            field_op = "self.rec_array['%s'] %s '%s'" % (field,op,target)
            mask &= eval(field_op)
        
        selected_sales = self.rec_array['sales'][mask]
        
        return np.sum(selected_sales)
```

Based on this `rec_array`, given the data

```
author = 4*["Shakespeare"]+ 2*["Dante"]
book = 2*["Hamlet"] + 2*["Romeo"] + 2*["Inferno"]
year = 3*["2000", "2001"]
sales = [104.2, 99.0, 27.0, 19.0, 11.6, 12.6]
```

we create an instance

```
test = rec_array()
test.add_record(author,book,year,sales)
```

If, for example, you want the sales of Shakespeare's Romeo, you can simply do this

```
test.get_view([["author","==","Shakespeare"],["book","==","Romeo"]])
```

the output is 46.0

or, you can also do

```
test.get_view([["author","==","Shakespeare"],["year","<=","2000"]])
```

the output is 131.2

Answer (score 5):

For the data-structure you could define the following class:

```
class Cube:

    def __init__(self, row_index, col_index, data):
        self.row_index = {r: i for i, r in enumerate(row_index)}
        self.col_index = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(col_index)}
        self.data = data

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        row, col = item
        return self.data[self.row_index[row] , self.col_index[col]]

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.data)
```

Basically a light wrapper around a two-dimensional numpy array. For computing the cross tabulation you could do something like this:

```
def _x_tab(rows, columns, values):
    """Function for computing the cross-tab of simple arrays"""
    unique_values_all_cols, idx = zip(*(np.unique(col, return_inverse=True) for col in [rows, columns]))

    shape_xt = [uniq_vals_col.size for uniq_vals_col in unique_values_all_cols]

    xt = np.zeros(shape_xt, dtype=np.float)
    np.add.at(xt, idx, values)

    return unique_values_all_cols, xt


def make_index(a, r):
    """Make array of tuples"""
    l = [tuple(row) for row in a[:, r]]
    return make_object_array(l)


def make_object_array(l):
    a = np.empty(len(l), dtype=object)
    a[:] = l
    return a


def fill_label(ar, le):
    """Fill missing parts with ALL label"""
    missing = tuple(["ALL"] * le)
    return [(e + missing)[:le] for e in ar]

def x_tab(rows, cols, values):
    """Main function for cross tabulation"""
    _, l_cols = rows.shape

    total_agg = []
    total_idx = []
    for i in range(l_cols + 1):
        (idx, _), agg = _x_tab(make_index(rows, list(range(i))), cols, values)
        total_idx.extend(fill_label(idx, l_cols))
        total_agg.append(agg)

    stacked_agg = np.vstack(total_agg)
    stacked_agg_total = stacked_agg.sum(axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)

    return Cube(total_idx, list(dict.fromkeys(cols)), np.concatenate((stacked_agg, stacked_agg_total), axis=1))
```

Suppose as input an `arr` array:

```
[['Shakespeare' 'Hamlet' 2000 104.2]
 ['Shakespeare' 'Hamlet' 2001 99.0]
 ['Shakespeare' 'Romeo' 2000 27.0]
 ['Shakespeare' 'Romeo' 2001 19.0]
 ['Dante' 'Inferno' 2000 11.6]
 ['Dante' 'Inferno' 2001 12.6]]
```

Then `x_tab` can be called like this:

```
result = x_tab(arr[:, [0, 1]], arr[:, 2], arr[:, 3])
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
array([[142.8, 130.6, 273.4],
       [ 11.6,  12.6,  24.2],
       [131.2, 118. , 249.2],
       [ 11.6,  12.6,  24.2],
       [104.2,  99. , 203.2],
       [ 27. ,  19. ,  46. ]])
```

Note that this representation (repr) is just for the purpose of showing the results, you can change it at you see fit. Then you can access the cells of the cube as follows:

```
print(result[('Dante', 'ALL'), 2001])
print(result[('Dante', 'Inferno'), 2001])
print(result[('Shakespeare', 'Hamlet'), 2000])
```

**Output**

```
12.6
12.6
104.2
```

Notice that the bulk of the operations are in the _x_tab function, which uses pure numpy functions. At the same time it provides a flexible interface for any aggregation function you choose, just change the [ufunc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#universal-functions-ufunc) at this line:

```
np.add.at(xt, idx, values)
```

by any other from this [list](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#math-operations). For more information see the documentation on the [at](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) operator.

A working copy of the code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/mesejo/15dbc9132ca0f3d15f35f0f7ad2ff190). The above is based on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/alexland/d6d64d3f634895b9dc8e).

**Note**
This assumes you are passing multiple columns for the index (rows parameter).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a sketch of a solution, obviously you'd wrap in helper functions and classes to provide an easy interface. The idea is you map each unique name to an index (sequential here for simplicity) and then use that as the index to store the value in an array. It is sub-optimal in that you have to pad an array to the maximum size of the largest number of different items. The array is zeros otherwise so don't get included in sums. You could consider mask arrays and mask sum if you want to avoid adding zero elements.

```
import numpy as np

def get_dict(x):
    return {a:i for i, a in enumerate(set(x))}

#Mapping name to unique contiguous numbers (obviously put in a fn or class)
author = 4*["Shakespeare"]+ 2*["Dante"]
book = 2*["Hamlet"] + 2*["Romeo"] + 2*["Inferno"]
year = 3*["2000", "2001"]
sales = [104.2, 99.0, 27.0, 19.0, 11.6, 12.6]

#Define dictonary of indices
d = get_dict(author)
d.update(get_dict(book))
d.update(get_dict(year)) 

#Index values to put in multi-dimension array
ai = [d[i] for i in author]
bi = [d[i] for i in book]
yi = [d[i] for i in year]

#Pad array up to maximum size
A = np.zeros([np.max(ai)+1, np.max(bi)+1, np.max(yi)+1])

#Store elements with unique name as index in 3D datacube
for n in range(len(sales)):
    i = ai[n]; j = bi[n]; k = yi[n]
    A[i,j,k] = sales[n]

#Now we can get the various sums, for example all sales
print("Total=", np.sum(A))

#All shakespeare (0)
print("All shakespeare=", np.sum(A[d["Shakespeare"],:,:]))

#All year 2001
print("All year 2001", np.sum(A[:,:,d["2001"]]))

#All Shakespeare in 2000
print("All Shakespeare in 2000", np.sum(A[d["Shakespeare"],:,d["2000"]]))
```

Comment: interesting approach, thank you! Could you please briefly explain what the `ai`, `bi`, `yi` variables are?

Comment: Sorry, bad naming. Just arrays of the indices corresponding to unqiue strings, i.e. author index (ai), book index (bi) and year index (yi). You would use a function to generate this hashing from the strings but this needs to be sequential or you get gaps in you arrays ( and the advantage of numpy arrays are contiguous data)

Answer (score 3):

Just the class initialization:

```
import numpy as np

class Olap:
    def __init__(self, values, headers, *locators):
        self.labels = []
        self.indices = []
        self.headers = headers
        self.shape = (len(l) for l in locators)
        for loc in locators:
            unique, ix = np.unique(loc, return_inverse = True)
            self.labels.append(unique)
            self.indices.append(ix)
        self.arr   = np.zeros(self.shape)
        self.count = np.zeros(self.shape, dtype = int)
        np.add.at(self.arr, tuple(self.indices), values)
        np.add.at(self.count, tuple(self.indices), np.ones(values.shape))

author = 4*["Shakespeare"]+ 2*["Dante"]
book = 2*["Hamlet"] + 2*["Romeo"] + 2*["Inferno"]
year = 3*["2000", "2001"]
sales = [104.2, 99.0, 27.0, 19.0, 11.6, 12.6]


olap = Olap(sales, ["author", "book", "year"], author, book, year)
```

From there you can create summing functions using `self.arr.sum()` along different axes, and can even average by using `self.count.sum()` as well.  You'll probably want some way to add more data (once again using `np.add.at` to put them into `arr`) - but your data structure is now Nd instead of tabular, which should give it the same benefits for high-dimensional data that `pivot` does.

Not about to put all that into code (even for 400 rep) but it doesn't seem too complex once you make the multidimensional data structure.